react -native doctor command failing
Getting error at Android SDK line
Error : SDK Versions Mismatching.
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions found: 34.0.0, 35.0.0
Version supported: .b34.0.0

PS F:\S\t\ReactNativeProjects\reactexpo1> npx react-native doctor
⠋ Running diagnostics...(node:9244) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
⠹ Running diagnostics...* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 34.0.0, 35.0.0
   - Version supported: .b34.0.0

Errors:   1
Warnings: 1

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.

When i will run, it should work properly.
npx react-native doctor


You dont have the required Android Sdk installed on your machine. Press e it should fix the issue.

Did it like a million times?

you would require to restart to system sometimes. Did you tried to run your app?
